# reflected greater than magic methods

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am in need of a reflected magic method "greater than" and there does not appear to be one. Here is the situation. I have a class which keeps track of units. It is call Property. I have the magic method setup to handle comparisons, but it does not work when I put the Property on the right side. Here is an example:

```
class Property():
def __init__(self, input, units):
    self.value = input
    self.units = units


def __gt__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Property):
        return self.value.__gt__(other.value)
    else:
        return self.value.__gt__(other)

def __float__(self):
    return float(self.value)

if __name__=='__main__':

    x = Property(1.,'kg')
    y = Property(0.,'kg')
    print y > x
    print float(y) > x
    print y > float(x)
```

So if you run this you will see the output is: False, True, False because the middle example is executing float > Property which uses the built in > not the > I have defined using magic methods. I need a magic method that will be used when the Property is on the right hand side. Is that not a thing? If not, how can I write this so that any combination of values and my own class can be compared. I would like to not have any rules for comparisons. IE, I don't want to just never be able to compare a float to a property.

Comment: Be careful using the word "reflected" for this, as Reflection has a specific and unrelated meaning in Computer Science. Perhaps "reversed" would be a better choice?

Comment: @IMSoP The Python docs use the phrase "reflected operands" here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__ Granted, this is a different case, because ordering operators do not have the  [commutative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). Still, I wouldn't say this is entirely unrelated from the word "reflected" in the sense of "look back on" which is used in expressions like `a op b` where the object a's op method can't handle an object of b's type.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Someone else's poor choice of word, not yours, then, and too late to fix it now. :)

Comment: Yeah, I am by know means and expert on these things. I am just a humble mechanical engineer. I just used the word that seems to mean what I mean based on the nomenclature that is out there: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator to create the missing comparison methods for you:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Property():
    ...
```

Then you get False, False, False. Do make sure to read its documentation, though.

Comment: This works great! Although, the documentation makes it seem pretty magical, I have no idea what it is really doing. But I guess that is life!

Comment: Well to see what it is really doing, just look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L192) :-)

Answer (score 3):

`__lt__` is `__gt__`'s counterpart; you'll need to implement `__lt__`. While you're at it, you should probably implement `__le__` and `__ge__`.

Comment: This is just the kind of thing I want to avoid. I have all these implemented, but I don't want there to be an arbitrary rule that my own class can only go on the left side of the operator. I am not the only one who will be using this class so it needs to be robust. This won't work.

Comment: @Murenrb: No, it will work. In fact, it's exactly what `functools.total_ordering` does for you, although that method has a few complications.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've declared the `__float__()` method, you could always write it as:

```
print float(y) > float(x)
```